# Avoiding a cataclysmic meteor shower

Tags: science-based, survival, transportation, meteor

With what is available, with means of transportation or method, what would be best strategy to stay on the opposite side of the Earth during a cataclysmic meteor shower that may last for days?

Comment: If it lasts for days there is no "opposite side of the earth" it is hitting on all sides.

Answer (score 6):

1. Why would it matter on what side of the Earth one was if a *"cataclysmic meteor shower"* hit? Everybody is dead anyhow.
2. The linear speed of rotation of the Earth depends on latitude. It's 1,667 km/h (900 knots) at the Equator, but only half that, 833 km/h (450 knots) at 60° latitude. Quite a few business jets, such as the beautiful [Bombardier Global 7500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Global_7500), can cruise at such speed.
3. The problem is that half a day later, the *"opposite side of the Earth"* is actually the side which first took the hit. Infrastructure is kaputt, there are no functional airports... As they say, when confronted with a cataclysmic meteor shower, one can run but one can't hide.

Comment: Not to mention the amount of dust is more than capable of bringing (jet) planes down, just look at the last larger volcano events, and those were tiny in comparison to what OP imagines with their meteors

Comment: Going all the way to the poles would help for that, but yeah, point #1 is very relevant here.

Comment: #2 The question states that it lasts for "days". No airplane capable of cruising at sufficient speed can remain airborne for such a long time.

Comment: @vsz: Yes, the aeroplane will need refueling. That's why point 3 is so important.

Comment: Speed of Earth rotation shall not be measured in knots. Knots are relative to the motion of air/water through which the body travels, and make no sense in this context. It shall be just mph.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain that a "cataclysmic meteor shower" is possible.

Remember that a meteor is not a physical object.

A meteoroid is a solid physical object floating in interplanetary space.  A meteoroid is defined as being larger than a grain ofspace dust but smaller than an asteroid, the dividing line being that astroids are large enough tobe detected before entering Earth's atmosphere and meteoroids are not.  Currently the dividing line is having a diameter of about 1 meter (about 3.28 feet).

A meteoroid which enters Earth's atmopshere and does not explode or vaporize from interaction with the atmosphere but lands on Earth as a more or less intact solid object is called a meteorite.

And when a meteoroid or asteroid passes through the atmopshere it creates a path of superheated air until it is vaporized, explodes, or slows down.  And from the ground the path of superheated air is seen as glowing line in the sky.  That is a meteor.

Nobody is ever hurt by seeing meteors - except in the novel  *The Day of the Triffids* (1951) by John Wyndham.

Most meteors in a meteor shower are produced by objects smaller than a grain of sand  which vaporize before reaching the surface.

And the particles in a meteor shower are much closer together than ordinary meteoroids, but are still separated by miles.

Coud there be an asteroid shower with asteroids at least a few meters or tens of meters in diameter, large enough to explode with the power of nuclear bombs in the air?  If their explosions cause damage on the ground over a radius of a mile or two and are separated by a few miles or tens of miles, that would make the odds of being within a blast area too high for the comfort of many people who would want to get on the opposite side of the planet to avoid any chance being caught in a blast.

I note that the Earth travels along an arc of about 0.98 degree of its orbit during a single day.  The circumference of Earth's orbit is about 940 kilometers, or584 milllion miles, so the Earth travels about 2,571,944 kilometers or about 1,646,926 miles per day.

So if the asteroid swarm has a diameter of one day's travel, it will be about 2,571,944 kilometers or about 1,646,926 miles.  And if there are a bunch of asteroids weighing tens or hundreds or thousands of tons each spaced about every thousand miles or so in a roughly spherical volume with a diameter of millions of kilometers or miles that is going to be be a rather large total mass.

My rough calculations indicate that for every quintillion cubic miles of the asteroid swarm there should be about a billion asteroids with masses of tens, hundreds, or thousands of tons.

My guess is that such a swarm of asteroids could be produced by a large asteroid headed for Earth, detected too late to use long term deflection methods.  Instead a hole would be drilled into the asteroid by conventional or atomic explosions and then a very powerful nuclear bomb, maybe a Tsar Bomba type, would be inserted into the interior of the asteroid and exploded, varporizing vast amounts of asteroid material, which will push the asteroid apart.  The pieces would be pushed away from the center of the asteroid and and after months might be spread out over a volume with a radius of millions of miles or kilometers, and thus Earth would be impacted by only a minority of the pieces as it passed through the asteroid swarm.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a submarine, capable to dive deep below the direct impact. Even a "tsunami" is not as bad under water. You would want travel along under water canyons, not as deep as you can. Above water impacts may create sudden pressure spikes.

If earth plows into the asteroids straight on (as you imply with them coming from the same side - the poles may provide additional protection.

If you want inspiration, may i recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves